# Swift, FirebaseAuth: After unlinking provider user.providerData still contains providerID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

After I have run the required methods to unlink the password provider, it still appears when I query it using user.providerData. The FirebaseAuth-Console registers that the password providers has been unlinked, also if I run the unlink method again I get the appropriate error: "User was not linked to an account with the given provider."

Doing the same with facebook or google login runs without problems. The error only occurs if I unlink an additional password login.

***Only after I logout and login again the query is correct.***

All other changes are displayed immediately/correctly. Google link/unlik, facbeook unlink/link. Even the password link method is registered instantly in user.providerData, only the unlink method is not registered immediately.

Any Ideas?

---

Flow:

**1. Query providers IDs**

1.2. result -> user.providerData = facebook.com, password

**2. Execute unlink "password" provider method (runs without error)**

**3. Query provider IDs again**

3.1. ❌  result -> user.providerData = facebook.com, password

---

Query method:

```swift
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    for profile in user.providerData {

    // Id of the provider
    print(profile.providerID)
    }
} else {
    // No user is signed in.
}
```

Unlink method:

```swift
Auth.auth().currentUser?.unlink(fromProvider: "password", completion: { (user, error) in
   if let error = error {
      print(error)
   } else {
      print("successfully unlinked eMail & password login")
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has confirmed to me that this is a current bug.

They told me they were working on the issue, and will be available on the next release, but can't provide any details or exact timeline when this would be available.